# I want to specify the class (type) of the parameter

Tags: python

```
class PostgreSql():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    class User():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def set_dsn(self, connects_database: bool):
            self.dsn = "host={host} user={user} password={password} port={port}".format(
                host=self.host,
                user=self.user,
                password=self.password,
                port=self.port,
            )

            if connects_database==True:
                self.dsn = "{dsn} {database}".format(
                    dsn=self.dsn, 
                    database=self.database
                )

        def set_host(self, host: str):
            self.host = host

        def set_user(self, user: str, password: str):
            self.user = user
            self.password = password

        def set_port(self, port: str):
            self.port = port

        def set_database(self, database: str):
            self.database = database

    class Session():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def connect(self, dsn: str):
            self.con = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn)
            self.cur = self.con.cursor()

        def create_database(self, name: str):
            query = SQL("CREATE DATABASE {name}").format(name=Identifier(name))
            try:
                self.cur.execute(query=query)
            except DuplicateDatabase:
                print("{name} Database Already Created.".format(name=name))
            else:
                print("{name} Database Create.".format(name=name))

        def create_table(self, name: str, coulmn: str):
            """This function is create new table in database of instance connection.

            Args:
                name : Name of the table to be created.
                coulmn : Column in the table to be created. 
                Format is "(name data_type condition, name2 data_type2 condition2...)".
            """
            self.cur.execute(
                query=SQL("CREATE TABLE {name} %s;").format(name=Identifier(name)), 
                vars=[coulmn]
            )

        def create_tables(self, names: list, coulmn: str):
            """This function is create new tables in database of instance connection.

            Args:
                names : Names of the table to be created.
                coulmn : Column in the table to be created. 
                Format is "(name data_type condition, name2 data_type2 condition2...)".
            """
            for name in names:
                self.cur.execute(
                    query=SQL("CREATE TABLE {name} %s;").format(name=Identifier(name)), 
                    vars=[coulmn]
                )
```

full code

```
def connect(self, dsn: str):
    self.con = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn)
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
```

This is the source of the code I want to change.

```
def connect(self, dsn: User):
    self.con = psycopg2.connect(dsn=User.dsn)
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
```

I want the connect function to take a user class as a parameter, not a simple string class, and refer to the dsn of the user class.
However, the User class does not appear in the visual studio code, so it cannot be specified.
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3HFE.png)

Why can't the connect function read the User class?

Comment: What is the intended *purpose of* `class PostgreSql():`? Why not just have separate `User` and `Session` classes at the top level?

Comment: It seems more like `PostgreSql` is supposed to be a module rather than a class.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The reason is the user and session of postgresql.

Comment: As @KarlKnechtel says, the containing class seems to serve no purpose and should be removed, a module will do. However what you ask is possible, reference the class including the parent `PostgreSql.User` and add the line `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of your file https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be calling the class from its parent class :

```py
def connect(self, dsn: PostgreSql.User):
    self.con = psycopg2.connect(dsn=User.dsn)
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
```

and you should import `annotations`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```